# Turn screen off using C windows 8

Tags: c, windows-8, screen

I want to write a very tiny app using C that would turn the screen off or on. mapping keys to call a specific function should not be difficult.

Which are the system commands to turn the screen off or on on windows?

Thanks

Comment: What does "screen" mean? Do you want to power-off the physical monitor? Do you want to dim/lock the session? Is this intended for a desktop? laptop? phone?

Comment: Since He says on windows, I guess it's for a Windows PC. Therefore, the question is what means "turn screen off"

Comment: I answered this question in a few minutes by googling your two requirements. a) a free utility and b) creating a shortcut

Comment: I would like this, or as a script. Do you have a link to a safe download? i got one but not sure its not malware

Answer (score 2):

```
// Turn off monitor
Sleep(500); // Eliminate user's interaction for 500 ms
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);

// Turn on monitor
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) -1);

// Low power monitor
Sleep(500); // Eliminate user's interaction for 500 ms
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 1);
```

Note that

```
**1** - the display is going to low power.
**2** - the display is being shut off.
**-1** - the display is being turned on (undocumented value).
```